# Effective points clustering using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, clustering, spatial-cluster

I want to implement clustering points like here in the last example(with big and small points): https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/postgis-clustering-with-dbscan

I have a table in PostgreSQL with `location` column where I store coordinates. The type of this column is `GEOMETRY(Point, 3857)`. There are 800 000+ records in it and will be more.

I used `ST_CLusterDBSCAN` to cluster data but it takes 40+ minutes to process this dataset. My backend gives data to frontend in shape of `Mapbox Vector Tiles` using `ST_AsMVT` and the speed of receiving data is crucial.

Is there some way to optimize clustering points? Maybe I should create another table with clustered data.

Comment: is your workflow to cluster the data on the fly when the frontend is calling the table?

Comment: Yes, I want to cluster data on the fly. I use Mapbox with deck.gl library for rendering points. I use MVTLayer which renders tiles with a bounding box and it does request to the backend every time the map is dragged.

Comment: assuming its properly indexed, thats a big table to clusterdb scan on the fly. I would recommend creating a separate clustered table and update it when data is added or changed. I don't know how much your data will be added, update or deleted

Comment: if it doesnt need to be a live dynamic data you might want to use pmtiles and cluster them with tippecanoe. I've rendered 7+ million points this way

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You could use your clustering query to create a materialized view, which can be refreshed concurrently.

Comment: What desired distance and density are you using, how are points distributed? I'm getting 0.4s on 80k rows, on a free db<>fiddle instance: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TbyD0w3). As to ziggy's remark above, I don't think `ST_ClusterDBSCAN()` is even capable of using an index: [here's a demo without the index+cluster](https://dbfiddle.uk/v6eUXsGe), performing only slightly worse on the same 80k sample. I also think it's better to cluster your points once, ahead of time, then add/reassign them as they get CRUDed.

Comment: If your data set doesn't change much, D T's [`materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) is a good idea, possibly with [`pg_ivm`](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/pg_ivm-18-released-2818/) *incremental maintenance* that could potentially let you avoid recomputing the whole thing.

Comment: @Zegarek I think the desired distance will vary because it will depend on the zoom level of the map